# Windows phone 8.1 - DateTime.Now object during runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I can't get DateTime.Now object during runtime. My code:

```
string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But when I debug this code, I get this message:

> timestamp error CS0012: The type 'DateTime' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral'.

I'am new to Windows Phone development and can't understand, what I should do?

Comment: Oh boy, this is a pretty usual problem with .net in general. Most of the times this is caused by having both: a reference to `mscorlib` and reference to `System.Runtime` in your `.csproj` file. Delete both of them manually, then add them by intellisense.

Comment: @TomasSmagurauskas sorry, but I don't understand. If I open `.csproj` file with text editor, there are not any entrance of `mscorlib` or `System.Runtime`.